# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected namespaced name "implements\IteratorAggregate", expecting "{"

Tags: php, веб-программирование, backend, redbeanphp, xampp

Хочу сделать систему регистрации на PHP и столкнулся с проблемой. Использую RedBean PHP и вот именно в файле rb.php походу есть ошибка. Когда запускаю index.php выводит следующее:

**Parse error: syntax error, unexpected namespaced name "implements\IteratorAggregate", expecting "{" in D:\xampp\htdocs\serdaragamyradow\libs\rb.php on line 1200**

Я попробовал поставить "{" в конец 1200-й строки, но к сожалению, это не помогло)

**1200-1220-ые строки файла *rb.php*:**

```
class OODBBean implements\IteratorAggregate,\ArrayAccess,\Countable,Jsonable {
    /**
     * FUSE error modes.
     */
    const C_ERR_IGNORE    = FALSE;
    const C_ERR_LOG       = 1;
    const C_ERR_NOTICE    = 2;
    const C_ERR_WARN      = 3;
    const C_ERR_EXCEPTION = 4;
    const C_ERR_FUNC      = 5;
    const C_ERR_FATAL     = 6;

    /**
     * @var boolean
     */
    protected static $errorHandlingFUSE = FALSE;

    /**
     * @var callable|NULL
     */
    protected static $errorHandler = NULL;
```

Comment: [Множественное наследование](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.inheritance.php) недоступно в PHP.

Comment: пробелы пробовали ставить там где нужно? Ещё, конечно, есть зависимость от версии php

Comment: Пробел после implements добавьте. И при чем тут множественное наследование я не очень понял, когда тут интерфейсы, коих может быть много.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Всего лишь надо было поставить ***пробел*** после **implements**. А я целый день мучился)

Comment: Спасибо, помогло. RedbeanPHP